# Strptime in R not returning expected result when adding seconds

Tags: r

At work we recently observed an unusual behaviour in our code, and I have nailed it down to the following statement having value FALSE, where it should be TRUE:

```
! strptime(strftime((strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")+3600*24),"%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y-%m-%d")%in%strptime(VsiB[,1],"%Y-%m-%d")
```

VsiB is a dataframe of some dates and values:

```
    DATEFROM    VALUE 
    1 2016-12-15 59.43073 
    2 2016-12-16 62.78324 
    3 2016-12-19 54.06673 
    4 2016-12-26 50.50698 
    5 2017-01-02 51.20186 
    6 2017-01-09 52.52000 
    7 2016-12-17 52.72573
```

and d is a date from this dataframe (problem in this case occured at d = 2016-12-17). 
This statement is basically checking, if the next date from d is contained in the dataframe VsiB. Well, in this instance, it is cartainly not.

The really curious part is, that for all the other countries (we are looping every the whole code for the total of 24 countries, 5 of which use exactly the same data as the country, where the error ocurred), that statement was TRUE.

It also happened only two times to this day, even though we run it every day twice.

The only explanation we could think of, was that

```
 strptime(strftime((strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")+3600*24),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

did not add a day (note +3600*24) to d. For example,

```
 strptime(strftime((strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")+3600*24-epsilon),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

for an epsilon > 0, would gain d, not d+1. So my question is, if there a possibility that some external conditions, as system time, etc., could distort the calculations enough, for that to happen?

P.S: I know that as.Date(d)+1 would solve it in an elegant manner, but I am nonetheless curious, if it is possible that strptime did not work correctly (plus any change could cause problems down the line).

> Sys.timezone()
>   [1] "Europe/Prague"
>   sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> locale:
>
> [1] LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250
>   [3] LC_MONETARY=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] rsconnect_0.4.3 tools_3.1.2

---

**Data**:

```
VsiB <- structure(list(DATEFROM = structure(c(17150, 17151, 17154, 17161, 
17168, 17175, 17152), class = "Date"), VALUE = c(59.43073, 62.78324, 
54.06673, 50.50698, 51.20186, 52.52, 52.72573)), .Names = c("DATEFROM", 
"VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Can you run `Sys.timezone()` and `sessionInfo()` in your console and add the results to your question?

Comment: Thank you for helping, I have uploaded requested command output into the question

Comment: Thank you; I can't actually run your code because it segfaults for me and I'm trying to figure out why that it.

Comment: Are you able to execute [this code](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/fdd7f0ab1f0ef807b43ce1f5c00f8e49#file-segfault-r)?

Comment: Yes, I was able to execute your code - the output was 'FALSE'...

Comment: You can not execute my code? Just try uploading VsiB and set d = VsiB[7,1]... But you won't be able to recreate the issue that has happened to me, and i'm almost certain that everything would prove to be fine - as I said, we've been running the exact same code twice a day for a while now, but the error has happened only on two occasions this whole time. I was trying to ask a little bit more general question - if it was, for some reason, possible that this would happen (strptime(day) + 3600*24 = day)  instead of day+1...